# Sikuli Selenium COmmands

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have done the integration of Sikuli with the Selenium now jut wanted to know if there is a link where I can learn all the commands I can use using Sikuli with Selenium. I tried googling and I learned about "App" commands is there any other document or link where i can learn more about commands that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sikuli documentation](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

It is the official site for Sikuli, and has pretty much all you need to know about Sikuli.